# Two different - django.db.utils.DataErrors

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm currently trying to deploy my project, which involves switching form SQLite to PosgreSQL instead, but everytime I change the Database URL & migrate, I get this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 564, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 152, in _alter_field
    super()._alter_field(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 719, in _alter_field
    self.execute(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(2)
```

Then when I try to login on my admin account, this is the error that's thrown -

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/

Django Version: 3.0.7
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'crispy_forms',
 'main',
 'shop',
 'bag',
 'checkout',
 'memberships']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 559, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

During handling of the above exception (UserMembership matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (value too long for type character varying(20)
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 138, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 78, in dispatch
    response = super(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin,
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 104, in post
    response = self.form_valid(form)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 151, in form_valid
    return form.login(self.request, redirect_url=success_url)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 195, in login
    ret = perform_login(request, self.user,
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 159, in perform_login
    adapter.login(request, user)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py", line 391, in login
    django_login(request, user)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 131, in login
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 20, in update_last_login
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 793, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/workspace/Waggy-Box/memberships/models.py", line 53, in post_save_usermembership_create
    user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 562, in get_or_create
    return self._create_object_from_params(kwargs, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 596, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1392, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: DataError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: value too long for type character varying(20)
```

Between the two different Dataerrors, I can't really figure out where it's going wrong.

I know the second one is to do with my login but, I've used AllAuth for this, so I'm not sure the workaround for this one?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change **max_length value from 2 to AnyNumberThatFits** of models.CharField

Comment: I haven't gotten any fields in my models.py files that have max_length=2 though this is what's confusing me